# Change part of Java class code after deploying to server as webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war

I have a Java servlet web app (.war) which I deployed to Tomcat Ubuntu server.

Can I change the content the Java classes at: *myProject/WEB-INF/classes/*
**without** re-export-and-deploy the entire app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add jar/classes into your app but you have to restart your Tomcat server

Comment: I just wants to change a little part of the content of existing class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could thought of below to re deploy your app without restarting tomcat:

1. Modify your `java` file
2. Generate `.class` file
3. Replace it with your existing file in Tomcat
4. Trigger your app restart by `touch`ing `WEB-INF/web.xml`

Comment: Great thank. but  what means 'touching WEB-INF/web.xml' in section 4?

Comment: editing web.xml file, change something may be add space and then save it. If you are on windows then check this [touch equivalent in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch)

Comment: Ok. got it. I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I don't recommend doing this because it can give unexpected results. I am aware that sometimes you need to do "quick-and-dirty" fix, but consider yourself warned :)

I assume you have a Web application, let's call it 'MyApp'. Go to `<TOMCAT-DIR>/webapps` and locate your `MyApp.war` file. Put new .class file into the `MyApp.war` (open it with some archiver) and then delete the folder `<TOMCAT-DIR>/webapps/MyApp`. Deleting the folder means undeployment for Tomcat. After some time, Tomcat will figure out that it has a .war file in his `<TOMCAT-DIR>/webapps` folder that needs to deploy and it will automatically do it. You will see in Tomcat's log something like:

```
Aug 25, 2015 9:24:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/MyApp]
Aug 25, 2015 9:24:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/MyApp.war
Aug 25, 2015 9:25:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/MyApp.war has finished in 21,937 ms
```

And there you go, you just refreshed your application without redeployment and without restarting server.

Comment: Ok. Sounds good. But what you say about the answer of Nitesh Virani ? ins't it easier?

Comment: @hcohen When I try his solution, there is also some activity in Tomcat's log, but I don't see new .class files in `<TOMCAT DIR>/webapps/MyApp` folder, so I am not sure if it refreshes the application. Try and let us know.